# Add CSS to a View or Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a MVC application which have its own CSS and it works perfectly.  My problem is that I want to use bootstrap popup at one of my view.  When I add Bootstap CSS to layout View it conflicts and disturbs my orignal CSS.  Now can some one please tell me how to include Bootstrap CSS at just that view where I require it. Any Example will be helpful thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below line after bootstrap.css

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/MYNEWCSS.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want the original CSS in that particular View, this would help,
The CSS file is referenced in the `_Layout.cshtml` file. So in order to reference your new CSS file instead of the original CSS, you have to explicitly set Layout of that View to `null` at the start of the page (as the page has the link to `_Layout.cshtml` by default) and add a link to your CSS, like

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<link href="@Url.Content("~/MYNEWCSS.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But the downside is, as you can expect, the _Layout.cshtml page's content won't be available in that particular page.
Let me know if it helps. Cheers.